# Understanding why two female first cousins share a lot of X-DNA?

Tags: x-dna, 23andme

I’m on 23andMe. I have a first cousin that I share a lot of xdna with. I am adopted but I am pretty sure she is related to my bio father.

I am wondering if I can tell if he is her mother’s brother or her father's brother?

The bar on the x is covered more than half.

Answer (score 2):

Without some additional information, no, you can't tell which of her parents you're related to based solely on the X-DNA match.

You need to review your shared matches with her. Can you figure out how these people are related to her? Can you ask her how they're related to her? Once you know which parent those people are related to her through, you'll know which parent you're related to her through.

Answer (score 2):

Your father got his one X from your grandmother.

Your cousin's father also got his one X from your grandmother. The two fathers would on average match 50% since your grandmother's 2 X's recombine when passed to her sons and they each get random parts of those 2 X's. Since you and your cousin are both female, you would both get your fathers' complete chromosome, so you would on average match each other 50%.

Your cousins' mother would have got one X from your grandmother and one from your grandfather. The grandfather's X is not passed down to sons, so your father did not get that and will not match to that. Therefore your father's one X chromosome can only match your cousin's mother's X from your grandmother. So again we have just one X from your grandmother matching another X from your grandmother.

So in both cases, the situation is the same and the theoretical expected X match is 50%, and either possibility is equally likely.